# Python - Web Scraping Entire Page

Tags: python, web-scraping

Looking for a general way to scrape an entire web page, with this one as an example:

https://www.boxscoregeeks.com/players?sort=wins_produced&direction=desc&season=2021

Tried the following:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import bs4

html = requests.get("https://www.boxscoregeeks.com/players?sort=wins_produced&direction=desc&season=2021", headers={"User-Agent": "XY"}).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
```

In both cases I get a lot of information but none from the big table in the middle of the page.

How do I in general scrape an entire web page as it appears to a human user like me?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "one fits all" solution, you always have to check website and behavior.

Content is provided dynamically via JavaScript, so you wont get it that simple way with `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`, but you should take a look at there api:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

jsonData = requests.get('https://www.boxscoregeeks.com/api/player_seasons').json()

pd.DataFrame(jsonData)

#or sort it by wins

pd.DataFrame(jsonData).sort_values(by='wins_produced', ascending=False)
```

#### Output

| id | name | games | minutes | per48_position_adj_prod | wins_produced | per48_wins_produced | per48_points | per48_rebounds | per48_assists | per48_points_over_par | exact_position | team_abbreviations | firstname | lastname | is_rookie | updated_at | position | secondary_position | url |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 191209 | Nikola Jokic | 61 | 2020.7 | 0.688922 | 15.5068 | 0.36835 | 37.7691 | 19.9297 | 11.687 | 8.37679 | 5 | den | Nikola | Jokic | False | March 14, 2022 15:42 UTC | C | C | /players/1500-nikola-jokic |
| 191158 | Chris Paul | 58 | 1916.08 | 0.46432 | 13.3606 | 0.334697 | 21.6943 | 6.51329 | 15.5066 | 7.33018 | 1 | pho | Chris | Paul | False | March 14, 2022 15:41 UTC | PG | PG | /players/211-chris-paul |
| 190781 | Giannis Antetokounmpo | 56 | 1836.3 | 0.57629 | 12.9864 | 0.339459 | 43.5484 | 16.7554 | 8.65218 | 7.47829 | 4.35506 | mil | Giannis | Antetokounmpo | False | March 14, 2022 15:41 UTC | PF | C | /players/1344-giannis-antetokounmpo |
| 191216 | Robert Williams | 54 | 1611.42 | 0.65683 | 12.9212 | 0.384891 | 16.0257 | 15.7278 | 3.30641 | 8.8912 | 4.62594 | bos | Robert | Williams | False | March 14, 2022 15:43 UTC | C | PF | /players/3372-robert-williams |
| 191258 | Rudy Gobert | 52 | 1662.03 | 0.693075 | 12.8982 | 0.372504 | 23.162 | 22.1223 | 1.70394 | 8.50596 | 5 | uth | Rudy | Gobert | False | March 14, 2022 15:41 UTC | C | C | /players/1378-rudy-gobert |
| 191049 | Tyrese Haliburton | 62 | 2174.88 | 0.364672 | 11.3213 | 0.249862 | 20.6577 | 5.53961 | 10.704 | 4.69182 | 1.74806 | sac,ind | Tyrese | Haliburton | False | March 14, 2022 15:40 UTC | SG | PG | /players/4157-tyrese-haliburton |
| 191100 | Dejounte Murray | 58 | 2016.35 | 0.396915 | 11.2593 | 0.268031 | 28.4712 | 11.7599 | 12.9501 | 5.25687 | 1.03584 | sas | Dejounte | Murray | False | March 14, 2022 15:40 UTC | PG | SG | /players/3188-dejounte-murray |

---

Another alternative could be to use `selenium`, to render website first and scrape based on that rendered `page_source`.

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

url = f'https://www.boxscoregeeks.com/players?sort=wins_produced&direction=desc&season=2021'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
df = pd.read_html(repr(driver.page_source))[0]
driver.close()
df
```

Comment: ahhh i see. thank you! is there a way to do the second version without chrome? i got a quite elaborate error from WebDriver manager that i assume is because i don't have chrome installed since it says "Current google-chrome version is UNKNOWN"

Comment: There are also other `driver` (firefox, edge,..) possible - Take a minute to read [`selenium docs`](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/install_drivers/)